# JS Warning in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having a big problem with this error here its showing up all over the site.

> Warning: file_get_contents(../sites/all/libraries/simile_timeline/timeline_js/timeline-api.js) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in _locale_parse_js_file() (line 1482 of ../html/includes/locale.inc).

I changed the files permission to 777 but still same message.
Anyone else who faced the same problem. or anyone who can help ? :)
Cheers

UPDATE
It doesn't only happen to the timeline-api.js, but to many other JS files like forms.js

Comment: Have you tried loading the file in your browser to see if it actually exists in that location?  http://www.example.com/sites/all/libraries/simile_timeline/timeline_js/timeline-api.js

Comment: @Noah - You really should not be able to browse to the file in that manner. And since Oby's chmod'd perms to 777 that implies he has access to the file system, so it would make more sense to check file_exists() there.

Comment: Are you writing your own code?

Comment: what was the last thing you do before this error came up ?

Comment: @Povylas - no, I am using the timeline module for drupal 7

Comment: @vishal - I am not really sure. But I first noticed it after I updated my drupal core.

Comment: @oby I once forgot to put my site in maintenance mode and had upgraded the core. did you forget to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the locale module has trouble in getting the right path if you use `base_path`.

You might have to load the library with the `add_library` function or `path_to_theme()` if you can locate it.

@see: https://drupal.org/node/1437710

Answer (score 0):

try adding the javascript files in template.php like this:

```
function THEMEHOOK_js_alter(&$javascript){
    $javascript[base_path().'/sites/all/libraries/simile_timeline/timeline_js/timeline-api.js'] = array(    
        "group" => -100,
        "weight" => -19.5,
        "version" => "1.0.0",
        "every_page" => true,
        "type" =>   "file",
        "scope" => "header",
        "cache" => true,
        "defer" => false,
        "preprocess" => true,
        "data" =>  base_path().'/sites/all/libraries/simile_timeline/timeline_js/timeline-api.js',
    );
}
```